# How to fix "warning illegal string"?

Tags: php, string, wordpress

I was working on another PHP version. But when i upload the site to client server due to Different PHP version i am getting these errors

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in
>   /homepages/3/d227794433/htdocs/flyefg/wp-content/plugins/gameplan-shortcodes/shortcodes/testimonial.php
>   on line 53
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'position' in
>   /homepages/3/d227794433/htdocs/flyefg/wp-content/plugins/gameplan-shortcodes/shortcodes/testimonial.php
>   on line 53
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'company' in
>   /homepages/3/d227794433/htdocs/flyefg/wp-content/plugins/gameplan-shortcodes/shortcodes/testimonial.php
>   on line 53
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in
>   /homepages/3/d227794433/htdocs/flyefg/wp-content/plugins/gameplan-shortcodes/shortcodes/testimonial.php
>   on line 53
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'position' in
>   /homepages/3/d227794433/htdocs/flyefg/wp-content/plugins/gameplan-shortcodes/shortcodes/testimonial.php
>   on line 53
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'company' in
>   /homepages/3/d227794433/htdocs/flyefg/wp-content/plugins/gameplan-shortcodes/shortcodes/testimonial.php
>   on line 53
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in
>   /homepages/3/d227794433/htdocs/flyefg/wp-content/plugins/gameplan-shortcodes/shortcodes/testimonial.php
>   on line 53
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'position' in
>   /homepages/3/d227794433/htdocs/flyefg/wp-content/plugins/gameplan-shortcodes/shortcodes/testimonial.php
>   on line 53
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'company' in
>   /homepages/3/d227794433/htdocs/flyefg/wp-content/plugins/gameplan-shortcodes/shortcodes/testimonial.php
>   on line 53

Code on Line 53 is

```
$output .= '<div class="name">'.$atts['name'].($atts['position']?', '.$atts['position']:'').($atts['company']?' - '.$atts['company']:'').'</div>';
```

Whole code is (Line 35-62)

```
function parse_testimonial_item($atts, $content, $id){
    $position = isset($atts['position']) ? $atts['position'] : '';
    $name = isset($atts['name']) ? $atts['name'] : '';
    $company = isset($atts['company']) ? $atts['company'] : '';
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-isotope');
    global $testimonial_slides;

    $output = '';
    if($testimonial_slides > 1){
        if(function_exists( 'head_slide' )){
            $output .= head_slide($testimonial_slides, '', '', array('page'=>true));
        }
    }
    $output .= '<div class="testimonial style-1">';
    $output .= '<div class="tt-content icon-quote-right">';
    $output .= strip_tags($content);
    $output .= '<div class="tt-tooltip"><!----></div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="name">'.$atts['name'].($atts['position']?', '.$atts['position']:'').($atts['company']?' - '.$atts['company']:'').'</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    if($testimonial_slides > 1){
        if(function_exists( 'footer_slide' )){
            $output .= footer_slide(array('page'=>true));
        }
    }
    return $output;

}
```

Thank you

Comment: I've removed the "urgent" queue-jumping in the title - all questions have equal value here. I don't advise you add that to any of your questions - volunteers will answer at their leisure here.

Comment: (You probably had the warnings suppressed on your old server. It is a good idea to suppress them on your new live server too, but only after you have fixed them in your development environment).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

the array variable $atts does not contain 'name,position' etc  thats why you are getting this error. check the data that is coming in the array $atts. Just replace $atts with @$atts problem solved.

Comment: 'Just replace `$atts` with `@$atts`' - problem covered up

Comment: Yep, hiding the bug is not ideal - it is better to fix it.

Comment: This is totally wrong. Hiding a bug is completely wrong

Answer (score 4):

At the very start of your function, you are checking if these values exist:

```
$position = isset($atts['position']) ? $atts['position'] : '';
$name = isset($atts['name']) ? $atts['name'] : '';
$company = isset($atts['company']) ? $atts['company'] : '';
```

So instead of using `$atts[...]` later on in your code, you should use the variables you have just set.

Also note that you can get rid of the ternary expressions later on if you set the values correctly right away:

```
$name = isset($atts['name']) ? $atts['name'] : '';
$position = isset($atts['position']) ? (', ' . $atts['position']) : '';
$company = isset($atts['company']) ? (' - ' . $atts['company']) : '';

...

$output .= '<div class="name">'.$name.$position.company.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that although you filtered the values in `$atts`, you're not re-using those variables.

Your code should look like this :

```
$output .= '<div class="name">'.$name.($position?', '.$position:'').($company?' - '.$company:'').'</div>';
```

Instead of this :

```
$output .= '<div class="name">'.$atts['name'].($atts['position']?', '.$atts['position']:'').($atts['company']?' - '.$atts['company']:'').'</div>';
```